# Schedule spider with SCRAPYD

Tags: scrapyd

I'am trying to schedule a spider run, i wrote:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=elettronica -d spider=Prokoo
```

return:

```
{"status": "error", "message": "'elettronica'"}
```

In scrapyd.log i see:

```
2014-04-16 17:55:16+0200 [HTTPChannel,8,87.18.14.190] 87.18.14.190 - - [16/Apr/2014:15:55:16 +0000] "GET /schedule.json HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
2014-04-16 17:55:35+0200 [HTTPChannel,10,127.0.0.1] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1618, in allContentReceived
        req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 773, in requestReceived
        self.process()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 132, in process
        self.render(resrc)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 167, in render
        body = resrc.render(self)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 18, in render
        return JsonResource.render(self, txrequest)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/txweb.py", line 10, in render
        r = resource.Resource.render(self, txrequest)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 216, in render
        return m(request)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 37, in render_POST
        self.root.scheduler.schedule(project, spider, **args)
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapyd/scheduler.py", line 15, in schedule
        q = self.queues[project]
    exceptions.KeyError: 'elettronica'
```

Anyone can help me?

Regards

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you have typed the name of the project wrong

check this line again

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=elettronica -d spider=Prokoo
```

and be sure to correct the project name `elettronica`